# is it possible to retrieve and print the data from a json object inside json array without using any index values and specific keys

Tags: javascript, java, json, windows, eclipse

```
[
    {
        "id": "628ba44f5a6de600071d16fa",
        "@baseType": "LogicalResource",
        "isBundle": false,
        "isMNP": false,
        "businessType": [],
        "category": [
            {
                "id": "628ba3ef5a6de600071d165f",
                "name": "Starterpack2",
                "description": "Starterpack2",
                "code": "RC17",
                "version": 2
            }}]
```

now i need to check and print the JSON Object inside the JSON Array if category is present then it should print  and in future if category is changed according to that if we pass parameter the output should print we don't hard code the code

i have tried by using key values it is coming but if the key value changes it is not printing the object
EX:-

```
[
    {
        "id": "628ba44f5a6de600071d16fa",
        "@baseType": "LogicalResource",
        "isBundle": false,
        "isMNP": false,
        "businessType": [],
        "category": [
            {
                "id": "628ba3ef5a6de600071d165f",
                "name": "Starterpack2",
                "description": "Starterpack2",
                "code": "RC17",
                "version": 2
            }}]
```

in the above code i have printed category object but if category changed to categories it is not printing so i want a code which can read the code and based on parameters user giving it should be print  the output

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**For Example:**

```
let a = [{"id": "628ba44f5a6de600071d16fa","category": [
        {
            "id": "628ba3ef5a6de600071d165f",
            "name": "Starterpack2",
            "description": "Starterpack2",
            "code": "RC17",
            "version": 2
        }]}]
        
      function print (values){return (a[0][`${values}`])}

     //now just pass any name like "category" or in future "categories"

     print("category")  //this will retrun the array.
```

Now modify with your requirements.

Comment: console.log(print("category")); to get an output in console as print is returning to no body :) , cant edit. Too many edits pending on SO.
Also, handle undefined values in the function by 

return (typeof a[0][`${values}`] != "undefined") ? a[0][`${values}`] : null

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get the value of the key(that can be parameterized).

```
const jsonArray = [
  {
    "id": "628ba44f5a6de600071d16fa",
    "@baseType": "LogicalResource",
    "isBundle": false,
    "isMNP": false,
    "businessType": [],
    "category": [
      {
        "id": "628ba3ef5a6de600071d165f",
        "name": "Starterpack2",
        "description": "Starterpack2",
        "code": "RC17",
        "version": 2
      }
    ]
  }
];

const parameter = "category";

const result = jsonArray.find(({ [parameter]: value }) => value);

if (result) {
  console.log(result);
} else {
  console.log(`No object found with ${parameter}`);
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, then please add your code snippet for better understanding.